# Error occurred while creating TTS audio for <slide_name>

Tags: adobe, text-to-speech, voice, adobe-captivate

This might be one the errors you might hit when you have just installed the Captivate voices 8 and try your for first TTS.It is quite annoying as there is nothing to be wrong in here. What could be the problem?

OS: OSX
Captivate version: 8.0.1
Captivate Voices Ver: 8

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.techyv.com/questions/adobe-captivate-shows-error-when-tried-generate-text-speech-audio) helped me with its first point. the fix was so simple but it took me lot of search and hope i save someone's time by this re-direction